# Php Mysql select query not working

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

The below query results in the following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'AccountId' in where clause is ambiguous

```
$select = $this->select()
            ->from(array('finance_account' => DB_TABLE_PREFIX . 'finance_account'), array(
                    'AccountId',
                    'ParentAccountId',
                    'AccountGroupId',
                    'AccountPath',
                    'AccountCode',
                    'AccountName',
                    'Description'
                ))
            ->joinLeft(array('ac' => DB_TABLE_PREFIX . 'customer'), 'finance_account.AccountId = ac.AccountId', array())
                    // using "array_unique()" to minimize db overhead
             ->where('AccountId IN (?)', array_unique($parentIds))
            ->setIntegrityCheck(false);
```

I don't have any other column to do the join. What am I supposed to do now?

Comment: You need to specify the table for `AccountId`, like `table.AccountId` because your query doesn't know which table to look at.

Comment: Wow!That saves.Thank you so much Jay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AccountId put  like finance_account.AccountId or ac.AccountId because query ambiguous  on which table to look at

$select = $this->select()
            ->from(array('finance_account' => DB_TABLE_PREFIX . 'finance_account'), array(
                    'AccountId',
                    'ParentAccountId',
                    'AccountGroupId',
                    'AccountPath',
                    'AccountCode',
                    'AccountName',
                    'Description'
                ))
            ->joinLeft(array('ac' => DB_TABLE_PREFIX . 'customer'), 'finance_account.AccountId = ac.AccountId', array())
                    // using "array_unique()" to minimize db overhead
             ->where('ac.AccountId IN (?)', array_unique($parentIds))
            ->setIntegrityCheck(false);